# I give image Url to ngx-Image-Cropper angular throw Error

Tags: angular, image, httpclient, ngx-image-cropper

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://url' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Get the image data from URL